# A loop in which three indices are changed

Tags: list-manipulation, procedural-programming

How could this piece of code be written in the `Table`, or as simply as possible?

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
LL = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4};

n = 1;
For[i = 1, i <= 2, i++, 
 For[j = 1, j <= 3, j++, {a[i, j] = LL[[n]], n = n + 1}]]

(*a[2, 3]

4*)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Table

```
ClearAll[a]
Table[a[i, j] = Partition[LL, 3][[i, j]], {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 3}];

{a[1, 3], a[2, 2], a[2, 3]}
```

> ```
>  {3, 5, 4}
> ```

```
ClearAll[a]
Table[a[i, j] = LL[[3 (i - 1)  + j]], {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 3}];

{a[1, 3], a[2, 2], a[2, 3]}
```

> ```
>  {3, 5, 4}
> ```

#### Array

```
ClearAll[b]
Array[(b[##] = Partition[LL, 3][[##]]) &, {2, 3}];

{b[1, 3], b[2, 2], b[2, 3]}
```

> ```
> {3, 5, 4}
> ```

```
ClearAll[b]
Array[(b[##] = LL[[3 (# - 1) + #2]]) &, {2, 3}];

{b[1, 3], b[2, 2], b[2, 3]}
```

> ```
> {3, 5, 4}
> ```

#### Do

```
ClearAll[c]
Do[c[Ceiling[k/3], Mod[k, 3, 1]] = LL[[k]], {k, Length @ LL}]

{c[1, 3], c[2, 2], c[2, 3]}
```

> ```
>  {3, 5, 4}
> ```

#### MapIndexed

```
ClearAll[d]
MapIndexed[(d[Ceiling[#2[[1]]/3], Mod[#2[[1]], 3, 1]] = #) &]@LL;

{d[1, 3], d[2, 2], d[2, 3]}
```

> ```
>  {3, 5, 4}
> ```

#### Scan

```
ClearAll[e]
Scan[Apply[(e[##] = LL[[#2 + 3 (# - 1)]]) &], Tuples[Range /@ {2, 3}]]

{e[1, 3], e[2, 2], e[2, 3]}
```

> ```
> {3, 5, 4}
> ```

#### MapIndexed + Scan

```
ClearAll[f]
Scan[MapApply[(f[#2, #3] = #) &], 
 MapIndexed[Flatten@{##} &, Partition[LL, 3], {2}]]

{f[1, 3], f[2, 2], f[2, 3]}
```

> ```
>  {3, 5, 4}
> ```

Answer (score 5):

> How could this piece of code be written in the Table, or as simple as
> possible?

I would just replace the `For` by `Do` to keep things simpler and more clear

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
LL = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4};
n = 1;
Do[
 Do[a[i, j] = LL[[n++]], {j, 1, 3}],
 {i, 1, 2}
 ]
```

Or are you looking for something using more fancy things like `#&/@..\/@@##*` in order to make the code shorter?

Try to avoid `For`. It is not really needed in Mathematica. I think Wolfram added it in order to help attract the C/C++ programmers to Mathematica.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution using `Array` and `ArrayReshape`:

```
Clear[a]

LL = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4};

Evaluate@Array[a, {2, 3}] = ArrayReshape[LL, {2, 3}];

a[2, 3]
(* 4 *)
```

But why not simply define `a` as a `List`? If you feel the `[[]]` too long to type, or need symbolic indexed notation in the first place e.g. `Clear[a]; a[[1, 2]] + a[[2, 3]]` but don't want to see the warning, then just make use of `Subscript` (you can input it easily by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>) and `Indexed`:

```
Clear[a, Subscript]

Subscript[a_, b__] := Indexed[a, {b}];

Subscript[a, 1, 3] + Subscript[a, 2, 2]
(* Indexed[a, {1, 3}] + Indexed[a, {2, 2}] *)

a = ArrayReshape[LL, {2, 3}];

Subscript[a, 1, 3] + Subscript[a, 2, 2]
(* 8 *)
```

[image]